# Refactoring a complicated if-condition

Tags: java, refactoring, conditional-statements, if-statement

Can anyone suggest best way to avoid most if conditions? I have below code, I want avoid most of cases if conditions, how to do it ? any solution is great help;

```
if (adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease) {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine) {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setCredit(0d);
        } else {
            entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setDebit(0d);
        }
    } else {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setDebit(0d);
        } else {
            entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setCredit(0d);
        }
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine) {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setDebit(0d);
        } else {
            entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setCredit(0d);
        }
    } else {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setCredit(0d);
        } else {
            entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setDebit(0d);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this works. I basically generalised your boolean logic. Next time, try drawing some diagrams to help clear your mind.

**Edit:** I'd like to point out from the comments to this post, that the XOR solution provided by Marcelo and BlueRaja is identical in function.

```
/* This is to avoid a crazy 3-way switch. Generalised.
 * Instead of using a complicated if-else branch, we can use the number of true
 * and false to entail the intended action. */
/* This is the same as a ^ b ^ c (chained XOR), 
 * which is used to count the parity of truth values. */
int a = adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease ? 1 : 0;
int b = adjustment.increaseVATLine ? 1 : 0;
int c = adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType ? 1 : 0;

if ((a + b + c) % 2 == 1)
{
    entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);          // Odd number of trues
    entry2.setCredit(0d);
}
else
{
    entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);         // Even number of trues
    entry2.setDebit(0d);
}
```

Comment: thanks Xavier Ho, your code helped. do u have any suggestion avoiding if conditions in most cases

Comment: I suggest you to read others' answers as well, as theirs are _much_ more generalised than my answer, which was produced to solve your _particular_ problem. Try to understand how boolean logic works, and see what you can do to simplify them. =]

Comment: Smart, but highly unreadable solution. This means hard to edit, maintain and understand. I will avoid writing that kind of "smart" code.

Comment: If you think about it, though, it's really not anywhere "worse" than half the other solutions presented here. While your solution takes a completely different approach, I argue that mine is more robust, and more portable/modifiable. If I were OP, I would also provide the original code (commented out) for clarify on what's been generalised, with a number next to each case. I got them on my editor here, and that's how I come to this solution.

Comment: I agree, it feels hackish to reimplement a basic operator (xor): `adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease ^ adjustment.increaseVATLine ^ adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType` (+ swap if and else blocks)

Comment: @kgiannakakis, @BlueRaja, please verify that my edits are correct and see if my argument is sound.

Comment: @XavierHo: (T^T)^F = F^F = F.  (F^F)^T = F^T = T.  (F^F)^F = F^F = F.  Thus, in truth, the actual XOR and Outcome columns are exactly the same.   Using XOR gives the correct result.  As a side note, in basic electrical engineering (and cryptography!) classes, you use XOR gates to count the parity of bytes, which is exactly what both of our solutions do.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Aha! Thanks. I've edited out the edited in mistake, then. +1

Comment: Xavier, whatever corrections you might have made, your truth-table is still wrong: `(a + b + c) % 2 == 1` and `a ^ b ^ c` are identical.

Comment: @Marcelo: Yes, I realise that. That's why I removed incorrect the truth table I made. Thanks.

Comment: As obscure as the new version is, the old version is nearly inscrutable and should be removed. A short paragraph explaining the intent suffices.

Answer (score 18):

How to go about this...  Let's extract a couple of methods, so we can better see the logic.

```
private void a() {
    entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
    entry2.setCredit(0d);
}
private void b() {
    entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
    entry2.setDebit(0d);
}

if (adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease) {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine) {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            a();
        } else {
            b();
        }
    } else {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            b();
        } else {
            a();
        }
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine) {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            b();
        } else {
            a();
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
}
```

So now, looking at it, that first block

```
if (adjustment.increaseVATLine) {
    if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        b();
    } else {
        a();
    }
}
```

just amounts to doing `a()` if `adjustment.increaseVATLine` has the same value as `adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType`, `b()` otherwise.  So we can reduce it:

```
if (adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease) {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine == adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine) {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            b();
        } else {
            a();
        }
    } else {
        if (adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
            a();
        } else {
            b();
        }
    }
}
```

And the remaining block is the same, just reversing `a()` and `b()`:

```
if (adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease) {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine == adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine == adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        b();
    } else {
        a();
    }
}
```

So we begin to see the logic.  If it's an increase, and the increaseVATLine matches the isSalesType, then we debit, otherwise credit, but if it's a decrease, then we credit only if they don't match.  What's a good way of expressing this?  Well, for one, name a() and b() smarter - now that we can see what they're doing

```
if (adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease) {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine == adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        debitEntry();
    } else {
        creditEntry();
    }
} else {
    if (adjustment.increaseVATLine == adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType) {
        creditEntry();
    } else {
        debitEntry();
    }
}
```

And now it's a little clearer still.  Debit the account when it's an increase account and an increase VAT line, and a sales type, or when it's a decrease and either it's a decrease VAT line OR it's a sales type, but not both.  Does this truth table help?  First column is `adjustmentAmount.isIncrease`; second is `adjustment.increaseVATLine`; third is `adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType`.  Fourth column is D for debit, C for credit; in parentheses are the number of TRUE values among the flags.

```
TTT -> D (3) 
TFF -> D (1) 
TTF -> C (2)
TFT -> C (2) 
FTT -> C (2) 
FFF -> C (0)
FTF -> D (1) 
FFT -> D (1)
```

Now you can see why @Xavier Ho's solution works; the odd totals are all debits, the even ones all credits.

This is just one exploratory path; I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I'm glad someone actually worked out why my solutions works. +1. However I now feel the XOR solutions are way better. =].

Answer (score 8):

I haven't thoroughly verified the logic, but this is the basic idea:

```
amt = adjustment.total
if (adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease
    ^ adjustment.increaseVATLine
    ^ adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType)
{
    amt = -amt;
}

entry2.setCredit(amt > 0 ? amt : 0);
entry2.setDebit(amt < 0 ? -amt : 0);
```

I should note that this logic is slightly different in that it correctly handles a negative value of `adjustment.total`, whereas the original seems to assume (perhaps correctly) that the value will always be non-negative.

Comment: thanks Marcelo Cantos, your code helped. do u have any suggestion avoiding if conditions in most cases

Comment: If I could give you a recipe, we wouldn't need programmers. In general, it's just a matter of practice and experience. Karnaugh maps can bring a certain degree of formality to the process, but I personally find it easier to manipulate the logic algebraically (e.g., the equation `!(expr1 && expr2) = !expr1 || !expr2` can simplify a problem, depending on the nature of the expressions). Also, as in the above case, look for redundancy and try to remove it;  again, there's no formal process for this that I am aware of, just practice and experience.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a truth table like this:

```
debit = ((isIncrease && increaseVATLine && !isSalesType) ||
         (isIncrease && !increaseVATLine && isSalesType) ||
         (!isIncrease && increaseVATLine && isSalesType) ||
         (!isIncrease && !increaseVATLine && !isSalesType)) ? 0 : adjustment.total;
entry2.setCredit(debit);
```

There are no ifs whatsoever and you can see easily in which cases the debit is 0. Same thing for the credit.

Answer (score 5):

To Martin Smith comment I'll add:

Remember, [Karnaugh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) can help you to simplify the condition of that if.

Comment: Aha, K-map! Brings me back to the good old first year college days. +1

Comment: Way to electrical engineer a solution!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Question has been answered, but I'll post there here for those who care for a cleaner solution:

```
//Set debit if exactly one or all three are true, else set credit
if(adjustment.adjustmentAccount.isIncrease ^ adjustment.increaseVATLine ^
   adjustment.vatItem.isSalesType)
{
    entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
    entry2.setCredit(0d);
}
else
{
    entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
    entry2.setDebit(0d);
}
```

Comment: "cleaner" is obviously in the eye of the beholder.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you only have 2 cases so you could combine them with OR AND etc.

```
        if (<case1expression>) {
            entry2.setCredit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setDebit(0d);
        } else {
            entry2.setDebit(adjustment.total);
            entry2.setCredit(0d);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have conditional logic (e.g. do something if a condition is met), why would you want to even try and avoid them?

Comment: Because there's a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you usually can do to ease the situation to some extent is use inheritance.

If you for example have two classes `Increase` and `NonIncrease` that are subclasses of the same superclass you can have a method `doSomething` that does - well - something according to whatever class you currently have. You then do not have to check "if object is  do X" but just call .doSomething() and it does whatever it is meant to do.

You can then go further and have more and more subclasses to further "refine" and "avoid more ifs".

There might be other possibilities (largely depending on your environment/requirements) like function pointers, delegates, the [strategy pattern (GoF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or such constructs.

Comment: Way to over engineer a solution!

Comment: Oh yes, that reminds me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101875/what-are-some-programming-questions-or-mistakes-you-get-wrong-only-as-you-get-b/2776764#2776764

Comment: Hmm - @BlueRaja: that seems a bit rude to me. If I remember correctly this is the first time I mention a design pattern on SO. And only because I am not smart enough to write clean code without help of much cleverer people. Maybe I should better not stick to the advide of mediocre programmers like Erich Gamma.

Comment: I agree that for the OPs case cleaning up the logic seems to do the trick. I think I got caught in the trap of Q&A vs. forum (i.e. answer the exact question vs. discuss a problem). Just out of curiosity: from the formulation of the OPs question ("`avoid most if conditions`"), how can you be sure she/he is not thinking in a much broader sense? That is by the way the reason I wrote "`usually can do`" and not "`answer to your exact question is`"...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to follow a design pattern.
A State based design pattern defines a class per each state.

The state class then encapsulates what is the course of action for that particular state.
This not only prevents a large junk of if -else statement mesh.

Comment: It avoids putting all of the if/else logic in one place by dispersing it through many classes!  That's not a bonus in my book.  (When in doubt, avoid following design patterns.)